# Windows hostname command in the context of a copy command

Tags: windows, cmd, copy, hostname

I wanted to copy a file and add the name of the computer to it.
So I assigned "hostname" to a variable and executed copy by the use of this variable.
However, the variable always returns "hostname" in the context of the copy command.
By simply using "%computername%" everything works fine. 
Could somebody explain that to me?

Doesn't work:

`set tmp=hostname 
copy file file_%tmp%`

Best regards 
Alex

Comment: Why wouldn't it behave as you describe. First If set to `hostname` then it will equal _hostname_. Second `tmp` is a reserved variable. Don't use it. `%temp%` is the MSDos temporary directory and `%tmp%` is the Windows temporary directory historically..

Comment: I don't really get this. Out of the copy command context %tmp% will return the name of my Computer (for example PC1). But within the copy command it always returns "hostname".

Comment: Show what happening by pasting tour CMD output as text.

Comment: I could make some kind of verbose copy output by xcopy. But my current os is German. Most likely this wouldn't make you happy.

Comment: Ah ok I think I got it. echo %var% also returns "hostname". Only typing "%var%" directly results in the computername somehow.

Answer (score 0):

(I'll use `var` as variable name, because `tmp` is a system variable, which should not be altered when you don't have a special need to do so)

`set var=hostname` sets the variable to the literal string `hostname`.
You can verify this with `set var` or `echo %var%`.

If you type just `%var%`, the parser expands the variable and tries to execute its value (which happens to be a valid command here). Verify with some nonsense as value:

```
set var=nonsense
%var%
```

and you'll get `'nonsense' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batchfile` (except you happen to have a file named like `nonsense.bat`, (or .cmd, .exe, .txt, xlsx, etc.)